# How do I abbreviate a phrase with an abbreviation?

Tags: abbreviations

Suppose I want to abbreviate British SEO Market. Which is the right way? BSEOM or BSM?

Comment: Me personally: BSM - Like GNU is an acronym for Gnu's not Unix :)

Comment: **BSEOM** , appears to denote clearly British SEO Market.

Comment: There is no right way. Use whatever meets your needs, balancing clarity with conciseness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to use BSEOM. My reason is:

UN is an acronym/abbreviation of United Nations as you know. If the latter one was the right way, they would abbreviate it as UESCO, not UNESCO*. Same for United States Coast Guard... It is USCG, not UCG.

*UNESCO - United Nations Educational, Scientific, and Cultural Organization